# How to add blur effect in ngx-bootstrap-modal

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-modal

I am using ngx-bootstrap in my project.
**modal.html**

```
<ng-template #modalMainNotification>
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title pull-left">{{notificationModal.title}}</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close pull-right" aria-label="Close" (click)="modalRef.hide()">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div [innerHTML]="notificationModal.content_plus | safeHtml"></div>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

It creates component in DOM
`<bs-modal-backdrop class="modal-backdrop fade in show"></bs-modal-backdrop>`

```
<modal-container ....></modal-container>
```

As I understand I should make `filter:blur(2px)` to `modal-backdrop` , but it has no effects.

**modal.scss**

```
.modal-backdrop {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: $zindex-modal-backdrop;
  background-color: $modal-backdrop-bg;
  filter: blur(4px); // no effect
  // Fade for backdrop
  &.fade { opacity: 0; }
  &.show { opacity: $modal-backdrop-opacity; }
}
```

**UPD 1:**
As an example you can check one of the example on stackblitz - [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngx-bootstrap-modal?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this issue by adding `backdrop-filter: blur(10px);` to `modal-container` and it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify style of your modal, then make sure to add `encapsulation` in your `modal` component:

**For an example:**

```js
@Component({
  selector: "app-modal",
  templateUrl: "./modal.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./modal.component.css"],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None // add encaptulation
})
```

And it's will working fine.

You can check at here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngx-bootstrap-modal-znbth2?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: anyway no correct blur effect on backdrop

Answer (score 0):

If this is expected to be globally in the app I would put the styling in the root style file style.scss in the root folder instead of in your component styling.

**style.scss:**

```
.modal-backdrop {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: $zindex-modal-backdrop;
  background-color: $modal-backdrop-bg;
  filter: blur(4px); // no effect
  // Fade for backdrop
  &.fade { opacity: 0; }
  &.show { opacity: $modal-backdrop-opacity; }
}
```

Comment: I have moved to root folder, blur effect not working anyway